XSLT conversion with recursion
I need to convert an XML document to HTML.
Input XML:
<items>
    <item no="1" par_no="0" user="Mike">Hi all!</item>
    <item no="2" par_no="1" user="Jane">Hi...</item>
    <item no="3" par_no="2" user="Pit"> says: wasap man?</item>
    <item no="4" par_no="2" user="Karol">are you ok?</item>
    <item no="5" par_no="4" user="Nick">I think he's not in the mood.</item>
    <item no="6" par_no="5" user="Karol">I just ask a question.</item>
    <item no="7" par_no="1" user="Pit">says: how are you?</item>
    <item no="8" par_no="7" user="Mike">fine!</item>
</items>

Output HTML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ul>
  <li><b>Mike</b> says: Hi all!
    <ul>
      <li><b>Jane</b>  says: Hi...
          <li><b>Pit</b> says: wasap man?
          <li><b>Karol</b> says: are you ok?
            <ul>
              <li><b>Nick</b> says: I tihnk he's not in the mood.
                <ul>
                  <li><b>Karol</b> says: I just ask a question.
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><b>Pit</b> says: how are you?
        <ul>
          <li><b>Mike</b> says: fine!
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

I tried to solve this problem. I got the code. The rows are being ordered, but I can't get the attachment. My XSL:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
 <xsl:output method="html" /> 
 <xsl:template match="items"> 
    <html> 
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@par_no=0]"/> 
            
        </ul>
    </html> 
 </xsl:template> 
 
 <xsl:template match="item">    
    
    <xsl:variable name="varNo" select="@no"/> 
    
        <li>
            <b><xsl:value-of select="@user"/></b>
            <xsl:text> says: </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        </li>   
 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//items/item[@par_no=$varNo]"> 
        <xsl:sort select="@par_no" data-type="number"/>                 
    </xsl:apply-templates> 
    
 </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>

I do not know where to insert  tags to get such a nested structure. Please help!

If you want a nested structure you should start by moving your xsl:apply-templates into the li element. What seems missing is the logic to decide when to output a ul element.

I think you could do simply (using only XSLT 1.0):
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:key name="chld" match="item" use="@par_no" />

<xsl:template match="/items">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item[@par_no='0']"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
        <b>
            <xsl:value-of select="@user"/>
        </b>
        <xsl:text> says: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('chld', @no)"/>
        </ul>
    </li>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

The result, as displayed in a browser, is:

Try it here.

In XSLT 3 you could solve it as follows:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
  
  <xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Test</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:key name="child" match="item" use="@par_no"/>

  <xsl:template match="items">
    <ul>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', '0')"/>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="@user"/></b>
        <xsl:text> says: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        <xsl:where-populated>
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('child', @no)"/>
          </ul>
        </xsl:where-populated>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>

The key and the templates will work the same in previous versions, you would need to replace the xsl:where-populated with a check whether key('child', @no) selects elements to output the ul only then:
  <xsl:template match="item">
    <li>
        <b><xsl:value-of select="@user"/></b>
        <xsl:text> says: </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/> 
        <xsl:variable name="children" select="key('child', @no)"/>
        <xsl:if test="$children">
          <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$children"/>
          </ul>
        </xsl:if>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

